# storing two different class objects in a vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to find a good way to store two different class objects within one vector each object having it's own location within the vector, so the objects can be stored and accessed later when needed.

I have used a structure but then I store everything which the structure has to the vector which isn't what I want, I'll give an example of what I mean.

```
Class A{
   public:
     void changeNumber(int x) {number = x;}
   private:
     int number;
};

Class B{
   public:
     void changeNumber(int x) {number = x;}
   private:
     int number;
};

struct Object{
   A a;
   B b;
};

Class Main{
   public:
     void storeObject(Object ob) {object.push_back(ob);}
   private:
     std::vector<Object> objects; //when an object is passed both A and B objects are stored within the vector in the same location
};
```

Is there a way where I can store two different class objects within one object but only pass one at a time to be stored so I has it's own index within the vector?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? What you probably want to have, is a common base class `class A : Base {...` and then store pointers to `Base` in `std::vector<Base*> objects`, but I might be missunderstanding the intention behind `struct Object`.

Comment: I am trying to store two different class objects which will have different functions and different variables but I want to store both of the class objects in one vector so it makes it easier for me to loop through the size of the vector and complete the tasks which need to be done. @mbschenkel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `A` and `B` have common functions and you'll be calling only these on the elements of a vector, you can take all common members and member functions and make a base class out of it. Then make `A` and `B` derived class of `Object`:

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual ~Object() = default;

    void changeNumber(int x) { number = x; }

private:
    int number;
};

class A : public Object
{
    // extension of Object
};

class B : public Object
{
    // extension of Object
};
```

In this case, `A` is no different from `B`, so everything is implemented in `Object`.

Finally, your vector will look like this:

```
std::vector<Object*> objects;
```

And here's more preferred solution with `std::shared_ptr` which frees the memory for you after the element is removed from the vector or destructed otherwise.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects;
```

Store object:

```
void storeObject(std::shared_ptr<Object> const& ob)
{
    objects.push_back(ob);
}

// Example calls
Main main;
main.storeObject(std::make_shared<Object>(A())); // store A
main.storeObject(new A()); // logically same as above

main.storeObject(std::make_shared<Object>(B())); // store B
main.storeObject(new B());
```

`boost::variant` is the way to go when storing multiple different types on which you cannot use inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so if class A and B inherit from the Object class but they also have their own separate functions I would be correct in saying it not be possible to store them both in one vector without using `boost::variant`? @LogicStuff

Comment: @Jack I don't know of any other way than mentioned here in answers. If you want to call like `objects[index]->functionOfA()` and `objects[index]->functionOfB()`, then not. But don't forget that there can be made some virtual function to be overriden. It may be even doable with inheritance and you might not know.

Comment: @LogicStuff what about std::any?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html). It is type that can represent a finite set of types, in your example you would have an

```
std::vector<boost::variant<A,B> > objects;
```

An alternative (which does not really fit your usecase, but may for future readers) is [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html). It can represent any type which is useful if you do not have a finite list of possible types at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to use your own "`variant` equivalent". You could do something along the lines of

```
struct Object{ 
    std::shared_ptr<A> a; 
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};

std::vector<Object> objects;

Object one; 
one.a = std::make_shared<A>();
objects.push_back(one);

Object two; 
two.b = std::make_shared<B>();
objects.push_back(two);

for(auto object: objects) {
     if(object.a) {
          object.a->changeNumber(1);
     } else if(object.b) {
          object.b->changeNumber(2);
     }
}
```

However, I still think that solving this with an appropriate inheritance scheme (as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019537/2861669)) is much cleaner.